# Replace regex pattern in array of strings - Logstash

Tags: logstash

I'm trying to remove url prefix from urls Array in logstash using ruby:
The url looks like this: urlArray = ['https://www.google.com','https://www.bcc.com']
I tried to use other array and do something like:

```
urlArray.each{ |url| newUrlArray.push(url.gsub("(https?://)?(www\.)?","")) }
```

I also tried:

```
newUrlArray = urlArray.map{ |url| url.gsub("(https?://)?(www\.)?","") }
```

I think I miss here something with the gsub.

Thanks

Comment: try to escape slashes .gsub("(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?","")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use [`slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#method-i-slice-21) and then capture the group you're interested in.

```rb
urlArray = [
  "https://www.google.com", 
  "https://www.bcc.com", 
  "http://hello.com", 
  "www.world.com"
]
newUrlArray = []

pattern = /(https?:\/\/)?(www.)?(.*)/

urlArray.each{ |url| newUrlArray.push(url.slice(pattern, 3)) }

puts newUrlArray
# google.com
# bcc.com
# hello.com
# world.com
```